# How can I add multiple values to an std::vector at once?

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I need to be able to tie the same variable together multiple times, regardless of which data type it is.

What I have:

```
utils::milliseconds first_variable = utils::seconds(10.1)

utils::milliseconds second_variable = utils::seconds(2.4)

std::vector<utils::milliseconds>{first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, first_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, second_variable, };
```

How can I make this so that I don't have to type the same variable 100s of times?

Comment: How about a couple of loops to set the values in the vector?

Comment: Try `std::vector<type>  result(number_of_first, first_variable);    result.insert(result.end(), number_of_second, second_variable);`

Comment: @Peter That would be constructor no. 3 on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector (and looks exactly like what the OP wants).

Comment: @Faz I love your example, except the vector is a bit short.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica  -  It's not obvious since the latest edit of the question (you'll need to scroll right in the code, to see that the OP wants two distinct values each inserted multiple times)  but the use of `vector::insert()` is also required.

Comment: @Denis spot on. Vote to close (no harm intended, Faz -- it's just that somebody else stumbled over this earlier and there is an archived solution).

Comment: @Peter "vec should be of the form {1,1,1,1,1} afterwards. Is there a clean c++ way to do so?"

Comment: @Peter Oh I see -- *this* OP. Yeah, they need an `insert()`as well.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica    Glad I didn't have to point out your mistake   <grin>

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop the add multiple values to a vector, here is an example:

```c
int foo = 2;
int bar = 3;

std::vector<int> vector;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  vector.push_back(foo);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  vector.push_back(bar);
}
```

The result will be a vector looking equivalent to using this:

```c
std::vector{foo, foo, bar, bar, bar};
```

**Explanation:**

`for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)` is a loop that runs as long as the condition `i < 2` is true. `i` is initialized with zero and incremented by `1` every time the loop runs, the loop will run 2 times.

`vector.push_back(foo)` appends the variable `foo` to the vector.

**Better solution:**

As @Peter pointed out in a comment, an `std::vector` can be filled with elements using it's constructor or the `insert()` function:

```c
int foo = 2;
int bar = 3;

std::vector<int> vector(2, foo);
vector.insert(vector.end(), 3, bar);
```

The `std::vector` constructor takes two arguments, the first one is the size (how many elements do you want to have inside your vector) and a value wich should be used to fill all elements.

The `insert()` method takes three arguments, the first specified the location of the insertion, it can be either `vector.begin()` or `vector.end()`. The second argument is the amount of elements to insert and the third arg specifies the value which should be used to fill the elements.